Dynamically unpacking Python tuples with structure checking using JIT compilation
This interesting unpacking function allows unpacking a nested tuple into the arguments of a function as its arguments, with structure checking support and only one function call overhead excluding one-time compilation cost.
def flatten_tuple(data, structure, cache={}):
    if not (unpacker := cache.get(structure)):

        def get_unstruct(structure, n_vars):
            if isinstance(structure, int):
                if structure == 0:
                    return "*x%d" % n_vars, n_vars + 1
                if structure == -1:
                    return "_", n_vars
                new_n_vars = n_vars + structure
                ret = ",".join("x%d" % i for i in range(n_vars, new_n_vars))
                n_vars = new_n_vars
                return ret, new_n_vars
            assert isinstance(structure, tuple)
            unstruct_code = "("
            for x in structure:
                unstruct_code_one, n_vars = get_unstruct(x, n_vars)
                unstruct_code += unstruct_code_one + ","
            return unstruct_code + ")", n_vars

        unstruct_code, n_vars = get_unstruct(structure, 0)
        local_dict = {}
        exec(
            compile("def unpacker(data):\n %s = data\n return x%s" %
                    (unstruct_code, ",x".join(map(str, range(n_vars)))),
                    "",
                    "exec",
                    dont_inherit=True), {}, local_dict)
        unpacker = local_dict["unpacker"]
    cache[structure] = unpacker
    return unpacker(data)

Usage example:
def f(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)
f(*flatten_tuple((10, (20, 30)), (1, (1, 1))))
# prints: 10 20 30

Any thoughts on how it can be improved?
Edit:
Here's a quick performance comparison against flat as given by @Reinderien:
def flat(t):
    if isinstance(t, tuple):
        for x in t:
            yield from flat(x)
    else:
        yield t

In [2]: def f(x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7):
   ...:     return x0+x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7
   ...: 

In [3]: %timeit f(*flat(((10,20,30),(40,50),(60,70,80))))
2.06 µs ± 69.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit f(*flatten_tuple(((10,20,30),(40,50),(60,70,80)), ((3,),(2,),(3,))))
383 ns ± 17.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)


Other than it being "interesting", what is the motivation to do this? It's vulnerable to making the program blow its stack, and will be slow.

To expand on the previous comment, why would it be necessary over the much simpler (albeit non-structure checking) def flat(t): if isinstance(t, tuple): for x in t: yield from flat(x) else: yield t ?

@301_Moved_Permanently it's exactly because it's structure-checking and it's (almost) as efficient as possible once the unpacker code is compiled for that particular structure.

@Reinderien it was meant to only handle structures that would have been easily unpacked via a destructuring assignment, so I highly doubt it will hit a stack limit in normal use cases

@Reinderien I guess you didn't understand what my code was doing. It's creating a function which is cached per structure and running the function. The function does exactly one destructuring assignment. So it definitely isn't "slow" unless you do it only a few times, in which case "slow" doesn't even matter.

motivation
As reflected in the comments,
the Review Context doesn't really set up why this would be helpful.
If I have this or that use case, it's unclear how I would
evaluate whether the OP code is a good match for that use case,
or if other (not mentioned) competing approaches would be a better fit.
readability
Python offers several tools so you can assist the Gentle Reader
in rapidly understanding what is going on,
which you chose not to use.
Optional type annotation, e.g. ... , n_vars: int) -> tuple[str, int]:,
would improve readability.
Adding a bunch of """docstrings""" would go a long way
toward improving readability.
Some of them might even use the >>>
doctest
syntax.
Note that even nested functions can have docstrings.
The "handle an integer" code is maybe doing enough
that it's worth breaking out a helper function,
if only to spell out its
contract.
maintainability
In the Review Context we get a hint that this code will
be called by an inner loop where every cycle counts.
But we find no automated
test suite.
So when a month from now a maintenance engineer
tinkers with the code,
it will be difficult to tell if it is "better" or not.
In particular, we'll have no measurements
for detecting a performance regression.
introspection
In the sample usage
f(*flatten_tuple((10, (20, 30)), (1, (1, 1))))

we only get to examine the input data.
If a reference to f was available, we could
ask
what args f wants to receive,
and verify they're compatible.
Phrasing your code as a decorator would be one way to approach that.
cache idiom
We see a nice, simple caching approach which is readily understood.
Nonetheless, it could be simplified slightly.
Such code is easier to reason about (and to test)
when there's a single unconditional code path
for consuming the cached value.
In the OP code we find
    if not (unpacker := cache.get(structure)):
        ... do stuff ...
        unpacker = local_dict["unpacker"]

    cache[structure] = unpacker
    return unpacker(data)

This requires the Gentle Reader to understand
some extra relationships.
Plus it always does a cache write, even on a cache hit,
which is slightly surprising.
Consider avoiding the
walrus
operator, and proceeding in two sequential steps.

ensure an entry is cached
use that entry

    if not structure in cache:
        ... do stuff ...
        cache[structure] = local_dict["unpacker"]

    unpacker = cache[structure]
    return unpacker(data)

Consider using a
@cache
or @lru_cache decorator.

nice catch with the cache write. I should have just done it inside the "if" branch..

I don't see the point of avoiding the walrus operator.
